# How can I use the OUTPUT clause to show what I just inserted with a SELECT?

Tags: sql-server

I have this Stored Procedure where I am trying to see what was just inserted into my table. This also includes an identity field called TestId. I am trying to see what was just inserted but VS2013 is showing me there is a syntax error even before I run the stored procedure. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
   INSERT INTO dbo.Test
          ( 
            Title,
            ExamId,
            CreatedBy,
            CreatedDate,
            ParentTestId,
            TopicId           
          )
    SELECT 
            Title,
            @CreatedBy,
            @CreatedDate,
            @TestId,
            TopicId  
    OUTPUT  INSERTED.Title -- Error here <<
    FROM    Test
    WHERE   TestId = @TestId;
```

I also tried putting the OUTPUT after the WHERE but it still gives me an "incorrect syntax" error.

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` clause should be before the `SELECT` clause, like so:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
      ( 
        Title,
        ExamId,
        CreatedBy,
        CreatedDate,
        ParentTestId,
        TopicId           
      )
OUTPUT  INSERTED.Title INTO #tbl
SELECT 
        Title,
        @CreatedBy,
        @CreatedDate,
        @TestId,
        TopicId      
FROM    Test
WHERE   TestId = @TestId;
```

Note the use of `OUTPUT...INTO` - you will need to store the values from `OUTPUT` into a temp table or table variable to use them later.

EDIT: If you wish to use a table variable instead, the syntax remains the same. Just change the temp table (`#tmp`) to a table variable `@tmp`. A table variable can be declared like so:

```
declare @tmp table(Title varchar(100))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how I can store a few of those values into the temp table and then how can I make it so that the SP returns those values after it runs?

Comment: I already have done that. `#tmp` is your temp table which will hold the values you want to include. In your stored procedure, you can just add a `SELECT` to retrieve from the temp table.

Comment: When I added your code it gives me an error saying "SQL71502: unresolved reference to object #tbl"

Comment: That's because I did not include the code to create the temp table. You will need to add that first. Alternatively, you may use a table variable, which you will also need to declare before you can use `OUTPUT...INTO` with it.

Comment: How would I do it with the table variable?

Comment: Exactly the same way. Please look up how to declare temp tables and table variables from MSDN if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: I can look it up but maybe it would be good if you could include an example. That way others who follow this question would be able to understand how to do this. Thanks